# kicad problem: Unconnected pads

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad

[image]

I finished the routing and the copper pour but this problem showed up.
I don't know what this even means, i thought some pours are not connected to ground so i connected jumpers between them the outter pour but nothing new happend.

[image]

I know it looks stupid but that's my first pcb ever and i feel like i don't know what i'm doing. Anyway, here's a photo of the pcb and the routing without the pour and i hope for any helpful comments over the full design...

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Whay are you want to achieve with connecting GND-GND with jumper? If you need two grounds (analog/digital) you need two symbols (e.g. GND-SGND). Also I did not get R9 10k resistor Vdd-GND, is it permanent load ? Anyway I think the "island" GND (with U2-13) is not connected to outer GND by a PCB wire so it complains, i.e. what are you asking for. But from my point schema generally makes no sense.

Comment: it was just a pull up resistor because there was some circuits for overload protection that controls this pin. anyway i'm not gonna use this circuit i'm just playing around with kicak.

Comment: and it seems that the program doesn't count jumpers as real connections and i don't know why, anyway i connectect the pins through the bottm layer and the error has gone.

Comment: Read my original text, answer is there. It's not about jumper but how do you try to design two grounds at PCB connected with jumper, not corresponding to schema where you have one GND.